# properly count the number of insertion sort comparisons

Tags: java, time-complexity, insertion-sort

```java
int comparisons = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
  int j = i;
  while (j > 0 && comp.compare(input[j - 1], input[j]) > 0) {
    if (comp.compare(input[j - 1], input[j]) > 0)
      comparisons++;
    E temp = input[j - 1];
    input[j - 1] = input[j];
    input[j] = temp;
    j--;
  }
  comparisons++;
}
```

I am trying to count the number of comparisons in an insertion sort. However my comparisons are not correct with the expected JUnit value.

Inputting:
{ 9, 5, 6, 7, 2, 8 } expects: 11 but was 13

inputting:
{ "how", "about", "dey", "da", "bears" }; expects: 7 but was 8

Are the test inputs expected values incorrect or is there some edge case i'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparison is done even if the condition is false and the command :`comparisons++`

Happens only when it’s true ;)